# Set icon badge when app updated

Tags: ios, xcode

My app contains a number of embedded exercises that are shown to the user during app usage. I plan to release regular updates of my app that contain additional exercises. After each (standard appstore app) update I would like to add a badge to the app icon showing the number of new exercises (=diff between old nbr and new update nbr exercises).

I would like to add the badge without the user needing to start the app, immediatly and automatically after the update.

How can this be done?
When ios updates your app, does it run for a brief period? In that case the logic could be implemented at that point....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're going to want to use a remote notification (aka Push) thats scheduled after you release an update. 
[Apple Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

The issue with this is the user might not update automatically (or refuse an update). So maybe you can have a push that says "We just released an update with X new exercises!", rather than implying they already have the data.

Comment: That could indeed be a good idea. However as I understand it push notifications require server side infrastructure. I would like to avoid this (this is also why the exercises are embedded inside the app bundle and not fetched from a central server). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
```

To do this through local notification you have to set the value in applicationIconBadgeNumber

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;// set here the value of badge
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I know how to set a badge that is not my question...

Comment: If you work little bit on the code that post, you could find your answer. You are just going to create a global number and pass it to the applicationIconBadgeNumber.

Comment: I have further detailed the question, it was not clear enough I feel.